# Change scrollOverflow to false in fullpage.js when modal is open

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js and bootstrap.
I need to be able to scroll, and it works fine using this:

```
$.fn.fullpage({
    scrollOverflow: true,
}
```

The problem is when I use Bootstrap modal. I'd like to be able to scroll the modal overlay and not scroll the body underneath. 
So, my question is, if it is possible to change scrollOverflow to false when the modal is open.

I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
         $fn.fullPage().setScrollOverflow(false);
    });

    $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
         $fn.fullPage().setScrollOverflow(true);
    });      

});
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: `overflow:hidden;` on the `<body>` when the modal is open should do the trick.

Comment: I have this on the code but it doesn't work because of fullpage.js scrollOverflow.

Comment: fullpage.js doesn't offer any option for it. You would need to do it by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fullpage.js doesn't provide any option for it. You would need to do it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use [afterRender](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterrender) callback

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    afterRender: function(){
        $('.modal')
            .on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
                $fn.fullPage().setScrollOverflow(false);
            })
            .on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
                $fn.fullPage().setScrollOverflow(true);
            });
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add **`normalScrollElements:'.modal'`** to the function...

```
$('#rp-wrapper').fullpage({
    anchors: ['Intro', 'AboutMe'],
    sectionsColor: ['#D6ECFF', '#1BBC9B'],
    normalScrollElements: '.modal',
    navigation: true,
    navigationPosition: 'right',
    navigationTooltips: ['Intro', 'About Me']
});
```

Comment: That won't change the fact that there's a scrolling section behind the modal.

Comment: The option 

normalScrollElements: '.modal-open .modal',

fixed the issue for me